# hashMap returning a value of zero for existing keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to code a simple two sum problem (given an array of unique ints, find the two that equal the required sum).

I'm using a hashmap to get the required amount (the sum-the current amount, and if you can find that in the map, those are your indices) with the hashmap setup as < key=integer in the array, value=index of that integer>. However, when I try to run that, it fails out on me. I end up returning zero and zero for my test case. I can't for the life of me figure out why. Thanks!
Using test case int nums = [3,2,4], int target=6. Expected answer = [1,2], given answer is [0,0]

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int[] returnArray = new int[2];
    Map<Integer,Integer> numsHash = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        numsHash.put(nums[i],i);
    }

    int tempSum=target;
    for(int j=0;j<nums.length;j++){

        if(numsHash.containsKey(tempSum-nums[j])){
            returnArray[1]=numsHash.get(nums[j]);
            returnArray[0]=numsHash.get(tempSum-nums[j]);
            return returnArray;
        }
        tempSum=target;
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you are checking all the elements of Hashmap while comparing one element of the array, and that also includes the element you are searching. At the beginning, when the array element is 3, you are searching `targetSum - nums[0]` i.e., `6-3=3` (the same element). Obviously 3 is already there and its index is 0. So you are getting `[0,0]` as result.

So while checking if the key `targetSum-nums[j]` is in the `HashMap`, also check if the result index is same as the searched index. If the result index is not same as the index of the searched element, then keep searching. Otherwise, skip to the next iteration.

Comment: Gotcha that makes sense. Thank you for the explanation!